# Android Recyclerview with editable elements not updating correctly with new element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So, I have a Recyclerview, where every element contains an Icon, a textview and a textedit.

[image]

The adapter looks like this:

```
class ZutatenSmallListAdaptermitEingabe internal constructor(
    context: Context, parent: NewRezeptActivity
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ZutatenSmallListAdaptermitEingabe.ZutatenViewHolder>() {

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var zutaten = emptyList<ZutatenData>()
    private var mengenedits = emptyList<RefZutatRezept>()
    private val context = context
    private val parent = parent



    inner class ZutatenViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val zutatenItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSmallZutat)
        val zutatenPicView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_SmallZutat)
        var zutatenMengenedit : EditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textedit_menge)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ZutatenViewHolder {
        var itemView :View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_small_mitmengeeingabe, parent, false)
        return ZutatenViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ZutatenViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = zutaten[position]
        val curpos = position
        holder.zutatenItemView.text = current.zutname
        holder.zutatenPicView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, current.bild))
        holder.zutatenItemView.setOnClickListener {
                parent.removeZutat(zutaten[position])
        }
        var richtigmengenedit =  mengenedits.firstOrNull() {it.zutatid == current.zutatid}
        if( richtigmengenedit != null) {
            holder.zutatenMengenedit.setText(richtigmengenedit.menge)
        }
        holder.zutatenMengenedit.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int){
                mengenedits[curpos].menge =  holder.zutatenMengenedit.text.toString()

            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    })
    }

    internal fun setZutaten(zutats: List<ZutatenData>) {
        this.zutaten = zutats
        var neueListe = emptyList<RefZutatRezept>()
        for(zut in zutaten){
            var element = mengenedits.firstOrNull(){it.zutatid == zut.zutatid}
            if( element!= null){
                neueListe += element
            }else{
                neueListe += RefZutatRezept( zut.zutatid, 0, "")
            }
        }
        mengenedits = neueListe
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = zutaten.size
}
```

I have a list "zutaten" where I store the elements I want to display and I have another List "mengenedits", where I store the text the user writes into the textedit.

I also have two functions where I can add and remove elements from the list. Then the new List ist set with setZutatem.

When I add or remove an element I still want to show the right text in the textedit.
But the problem is when the List "zutaten" updates, the list of "mengedits" changes correctly, but in the onBindViewHolder function it somehow gets messed up. The text of the secon element shows in the textedit of the first.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what's happening, but I think you should set some breakpoints (especially in that TextWatcher code) and debug it, and try to work out what's happening that way. Also, as far as I'm aware ``addTextChangedListener`` adds to *a list* of ``TextWatcher``s that get the updated text callback, and you're creating and adding a new one every time the ``ViewHolder`` is bound. That could end up with some screwy behaviour

Comment: Also the `TextWatcher`s you're creating basically update `mengenedits[currentPosition]`, right? But that value of `currentPosition` is fixed when the TextWatcher is created (the `curpos` variable goes out of scope when `onBindViewHolder` exits, the next time it runs is a completely new variable that Watcher doesn't know about). So if a specific `ViewHolder` displays position 0, it creates a `TextWatcher` that updates `mengenedits[0]`. If that same `ViewHolder` is reused to display position 9, it still has the watcher that edits `mengenedits[0]`, and that fires when you call ``setText`` for 9

Comment: Sorry if that's confusing, it's kinda hard to describe! And I don't know what the actual behaviour would be there, but that's where I'd look. Honestly I'd just set up the ``TextWatcher`` in the ``ViewHolder`` itself (so it only happens once), and make ``curpos`` a property on the ``ViewHolder``, so ``onBindViewHolder`` can set it and the TextWatcher can refer to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not shure what the porblem was, but I fixed it:

I am only adding and removing certain items, so instead of replacing the whole list, I just removed or added the specific item and instead of calling a notifyDataSetChanged(), I just called notifyItemInserted and notifyItemRemoved

So the functions for removing an adding looked like this:

```
    fun addZutat(zutat: ZutatenData){
        zutaten.add(zutat)
        mengenedits.add( RefZutatRezept( zutat.zutatid, 0, ""))
        notifyItemInserted(zutaten.size -1)
    }

    fun removeZutat(zutat: ZutatenData){
        val pos = zutaten.indexOf(zutat)
        zutaten.removeAt(pos)
        mengenedits.removeAt(pos)
        notifyItemRemoved(pos)
    }
```

Note: I also change the lists to MutableLists, because I wanted to call removeAt()